# State's href does not change when the interpolated ui-sref name changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have app where the next state name is dependent on the selection the user makes. I wanted to update the state name when the user makes a choice. The state name changes but the url does not update.

My code:

```
var app = angular.module('routerTest', ['ui.router']);

app.config(function($stateProvider){
$stateProvider
  .state('home', {
    template: '<div><h1>Home state</h1></div>',
    url: 'home'
  })
  .state('foo', {
    template: '<div><h1>Foo state</h1></div>',
    url: 'foo'
  })
  .state('bar', {
    template: '<div><h1>Bar state</h1></div>',
    url: 'bar'
  })
})
.controller('appController', function(){
  this.availableStates = ['home', 'foo', 'bar'];

  // once the state is defined, the href value does not change
  this.state = this.availableStates[0];
})
.run();
```

Main view:

```
<div ng-controller="appController as app">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="state in app.availableStates">
      <button type="button" ng-click="app.state=state">{{ state }}</button>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <a ui-sref="{{ app.state }}">My href does not change :(</a>
  <h3>View</h3>
  <div style="min-height: 100px; border: 1px solid red;" ui-view></div>
</div>
```

Is this an issue with the ui-router or am I doing something wrong ?

[I've prepared a plunk where you can see what I am trying to achieve](https://plnkr.co/edit/QWhutX?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this code to:

```
<button type="button" 
   ng-click="changeState(state)">{{ state }}</button>
```

Add in controller:

```
$scope.changeState = function(newState){
   this.state = newState;
   $state.go(newState);
}
```

Comment: This would be an possible workaround, but i'm curious if it's possible with <a> elements